# cursor go backward when triggered the regex in the replace, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, keyup

I have attached the link to fiddle to simulate the problem I got.

eg:
I entered 12345 > point the cursor in the middle 12|345 > type "space" > 123|45

the cursor will go backward after I type the "space".

**Question**: How can I make it stay at the same place as it is before?

[Here is the link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LkL1Lb5n/4/)

```
document.querySelector("#removeSpace").onkeyup =  function()
{

    var start = this.selectionStart,
        end = this.selectionEnd;

    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g,"");
    this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
};
```

Comment: Perhaps, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/gdL649cc/). Although you still can enter spaces, but they will get removed.

Comment: cool, but can you explain a bit about this function, I appreciate that.

function($0) 
{
offset=$0.length; return "";
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the whitespace was matched or not, and set the selection with the offset equal to the match length. However, to avoid the whitespace input, you may  use `input` event:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#removeSpace').bind('input', function(){
      var start = this.selectionStart,
            end = this.selectionEnd;
      var offset=0;
      this.value = this.value.replace(/\s+/g, function($0) {offset=$0.length; return "";});
      if (offset > 0)
        this.setSelectionRange(start-offset, end-offset);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="removeSpace" type="Text" />
```

The `replace(/\s+/g, function($0) {offset=$0.length; return "";})` part matches 1 or more whitespaces and passes them to the callback via `$0` variable. Its length is assigned to `offset` variable and is subtracted from the current start and end cursor positions. `return ""` removes the match, all the whitespaces found.

The same logic can be applied to fix your solution using `keyup`:

```js
document.querySelector("#removeSpace").onkeyup =  function()
{
    
    var start = this.selectionStart,
        end = this.selectionEnd;
    var offset=0;
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s+/g, function($0) {offset=$0.length; return "";});
    if (offset > 0)
     this.setSelectionRange(start-offset, end-offset);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="removeSpace" type="Text" />
```

Comment: very helpful answer and well explained, thanks for provide the solution, appreciate that.

Comment: why is that this solution doesn't work in safari 5.1.7?
the cursor will still going backward

Comment: @codingDummy I have no idea, I have never used Safari. I can't find any details on what there might be different. Perhaps, the `input` event is not supported. I added the code that should work for you even in Safari since it uses ECMAScript 5 regex related code, and is basically a fix for your code.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but onkeyup make things worse in safari, it will go back to the original problem. Well, thanks a lot.